# Replace randomly 1000 NA Values in a dataframe column with 0s, without overwriting 1s

Tags: r, random, replace, na, zero

I am trying to randomly replace 1000 NA values in a dataframe column with 0s. The column is composed only of NAs and 1s and it looks like this:

```
  Column
1 NA
2 1    
3 NA    
4 NA    
5 NA    
6 1    
7 NA
...
```

I want it to look something like this:

```
  Column
1 0
2 1    
3 NA    
4 0    
5 NA    
6 1    
7 NA
...
```

The column I am working with has more than 1000 rows, so there will be space for 0s and NAs in the end.

I tried something like this:

```
is.na(df_col[sample(seq(nrow(is.na(df_col))), 1000), "Column"]) <- 0
```

This, however, does not work. No NA values are replaced. If I take out the is.na()s it works, but the values 1 might get replaced and I do not want that. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: you have `is.na` twice. and `sample`? Try `df_col[is.na(df_col[,"Column"]),"Column"] <- 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to replace 1,000 NA values rather than choosing 1,000 indices and replacing them if they are NA. The following code finds the indices of `NA` values, then replaces a random sample of 1,000 of those indices with 0.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(x = rep(c(1, NA), times = 2000))
indices <- which(is.na(df$x))
df[sample(indices, 1000, replace = FALSE), "x"] <- 0
```

Comment: Yes, I was trying to replace directly and not via the indexes. Your solution seems to work perfectly, however. Just one question, though. If my dataframe is just a column can I just write its name where you put df$x ? Or is there a problem with that? Thank you very much!

Comment: If you don't want to store the indices in a variable, just replace `indices` inside `sample()` with the `which(is.na)` bit. But yes, replacing `df$x` with `df` should work in your case.

Comment: Ok, will do that. Thanks again for the help.